# Loading JSON object with special values as a string

Tags: javascript, python, json

I'm trying to create a string JSON object to load using the `json` module; however, I'm having some trouble since some of my values are the python `True` and `False` rather than unicode strings. For example, I want do the following:

```
>>> newDict = json.loads(u'{"firstKey": True, "secondKey": False}')
>>> newDict.get('firstKey') == True
True
```

but I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 336, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self._scanner.iterscan(s, **kw).next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/scanner.py", line 55, in iterscan
    rval, next_pos = action(m, context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 185, in JSONObject
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting object", s, end))
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 13 (char 13)
```

and of course if I change the `True` and `False` to `"True"` and `"False"`, my condition is not met either as they are now strings and `False` would be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use lowercase `true` and `false`?

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {'firstKey': True, 'secondKey': False}
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"secondKey": false, "firstKey": true}'
>>> s = json.dumps(d)
>>> json.loads(s) == d
True
```

Comment: ... which is due to the fact that JSON stands for "JavaScript object notation", so it has to be valid JavaScript, not Python. And JS indeed uses `true` and `false`.

Comment: @Sergey: It does not matter how it is in JavaScript, it has to conform to the JSON specification: http://json.org. Of course JSON was modeled after JavaScript object literals, but they are two independent technologies.

Comment: @FelixKling: from json.org's frontpage: "(JSON) is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language...", and also "JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript. Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript, it can be used in the language with no muss or fuss.". I just tried to explain to the OP why JSON uses (a subset of) JavaScript syntax and not Python's. Which are quite similar in this area, but with a few subtle differences.

Comment: @Sergey: Ok, I understand. I'm just a bit sensitive when people are saying something that sounds like "JSON is JavaScript" because that leads to a lot of confusion later on. But setting it in contrast to Python makes sense. No hard feelings!